# SQL problem with formulating a query where combinations are defined in another table

Tags: sql

I have a SQL situation for which I don't have a solution.

Combinations of locations are defined in table **PressureBox** in which DD and CR are both Foreign Keys to the Location table.

**Table Location**

```
+--------+--------+
| ID     | Name   |
+--------+--------+
| KPN1   | AA     |
| MIN2   | BB     |
| KGM10  | CC     |
| KST100 | DD     |
+--------+--------+
```

**Table PressureBox**

```
+--------+--------+
| DD     | CR     |
+--------+--------+
| KPN1   | KGM10  |
| MIN2   | KST100 |
+--------+--------+
```

I'm trying to get the following resultset:

```
+-------+-------+
| Loc1  | Loc2  |
+-------+-------+
| AA    | BB    |
| CC    | DD    |
+-------+-------+
```

(from table **Location**, *Name* aliased as *Loc1/Loc2*)

So for example, KPN1 + KGM10 must result in "AA | CC".

How can this be accomplished in SQL? Any ideas, solutions or hints are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: The result should be BB,DD for the second row of PressureBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Loc1.Name AS Loc1,
    Loc2.Name AS Loc2
FROM
    PressureBox PB
    JOIN Location Loc1 ON Loc1.ID = PB.DD
    JOIN Location Loc2 ON Loc2.ID = PB.CR
```